# Listbox bindind error scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-7, checkbox, listbox, scroll

I have a listbox(JumpListBox) with ~500 items.

Listbox template is a grid which have two columns - checkbox and image;

To reproduce problem: I've checked two items, then I do scrolling, then I can see that checkbox not corresponding to item which was selected. When I do scrolling back to the item I was selected I see that items are not selected, but other items was selected.

I recorded a   **[video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DakRc-7JvjA)** and you can see a problem.

Comment: It's very hard to guess based on your video. It would be better if you could show your ListBox XAML code, including the template.

Comment: This is a simple template. For example: Listbox with 500 elements and checkbox and textblock. Check a few elements and faster do scrolling, you will see a problem I have.